# python shift 3-d array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 3-dimensional array in python.  I want to shift the [z][y][x] "cube" on the first [z] index.  But the number of shifts will vary depending on [y] and [x].  In other words, I wish I could feed numpy.roll something like numpy.roll(3Darray, 2Dvector, axis=0), where 2Dvector would specify the amount of the shift for each [y][x].  Sorry if this is a poor description, I'm new to this.

Here's an example using a non-sense 3-D array.  The first 2-D slice is all integers, the second slice is upper case letters, the third is lower case letters.  I chose this just so it's more obvious what's "moving".

```
old_array([[[6 3 9]
            [4 4 8]
            [3 1 6]]

           [[A C F]
            [T Z Q]
            [L M P]]

           [[b z j]
            [q o k]
            [u y r]]])
```

Now I want to roll the first slice around to the 3rd slice IF the value in the first slice is less than 5.  The result would look like this:

```
new_array([[[6 C 9]
            [T Z 8]
            [L M 6]]

            [[A z F]
             [q o Q]
             [u y P]]

            [[b 3 j]
             [4 4 k]
             [3 1 r]]])
```

I've tried something like:

```
 a[a[0]<5] = np.roll(a[a[0]<5],1,axis=0)
```

but didn't get the result I wanted no matter what I chose for my axis setting.

Comment: Could you add a small example how the input would look like and the expected result?

Comment: Did the answer below work for you @user5905617 ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possible solution, which I've broken down in to manageable steps:

```
#roll the whole array
rolled_array = np.roll(old_array,-1,axis=0)

#Create a partial mask based on the first slice
mask_part = np.where(old_array[0,:,:] < 5 , True,False)

#Replicate the partial mask for the other two slices
mask_full = np.array([mask_part,mask_part,mask_part])

#apply the mask to numpy.where
new_array = np.where(mask_full,rolled_array,old_array)
```

Hope this helps.